# What is the mathematical shape of a projected spherical ellipse on the base of the hemisphere?

Tags: area, projective-geometry, spherical-geometry

The projection of a disk, with an arbitrary orientation, onto an sphere is an spherical ellipse(right image), I believe.

Now, what is the projection of this shperical ellipse on to the base plane of the hemisphere?
I cannot figure it out what geometry shap it is? Is it just compsed of two arc segments of two different ellipses? or an ellipse and a circle?

My motivation is to find the projected area of the disk on the hemisphere base plane and then to sample it.

Like this:
(left is projection of the spherical ellipse on the base plane of the hemisphere, and
right image is 3d view of the disk and it's projection on to the sphere)

[image]

Or this:

[image]